# How do you change the background color of a TabbedPanelItem in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change the background color on my tabs and change from the default grey color, but I can't manage to find out how to do it.

I have tried defining a canvas but that just ends up creating like a colored layer over the tab and then I can't read the text on the tab.

my .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

app=Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return app

mainApp().run()
```

main.kv file:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        height: 30

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            TabbedPanel:
                do_default_tab: False
                tab_width: self.parent.width/2
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: "Tab 1"
                    color: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                    markup: True
                    Label:
                        text: "contents of tab 1"
                        color: get_color_from_hex("#000000")
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgb: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos

                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: "Tab 2"
                    markup: True
                    Label:
                        text: "contents of tab 2"
                        color: get_color_from_hex("#000000")
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgb: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab is a class of TabbedPanelHeader and they have the following properties just like Button widget.

## Example

Add the following into kv file:

```
<TabbedPanelHeader>:
    background_normal: 'blue.png'
    background_down: 'red.png'
```

## Output

[image: Tab1 Pressed]
[image: Tab2 Pressed]

Comment: and how would you change the color of the text of the tab depending in whether it is pressed or not??